# Label Chrome Packaged App as "available for android"

Tags: manifest, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

On some apps in the Chrome web store you see 'available for Android Get it', for example Keep:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-notes-and-lis/hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki

I have tried to find instructions of how to label apps like so.
I know you can add the "**Runs Offline**" label by adding '`offline_enabled: true`,' in the manifest file, but I have not found anything similar for 'available for Android'.

Does anyone know how this is done, or how it works (if it is an automatic label or anything)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can contact the CWS dev support team at https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/ to get it resolved. Please make sure both the Android app and Chrome app have the same name and the same owner before you reach out to them.

Answer (score 0):

It has to have **same application name** and it will be automatically done for you.

Check one of my app, 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/143pets-cute-videos/bibagdnophfdhenhmhkjaoniginmgcka and links to 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fedmich.pets&hl=en-US

There is also official posts about this:

1. https://plus.google.com/+FrancoisBeaufort/posts/5fhFgvmAGYT
2. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-apps/jnvqM0rqu-0/BkEgRSOvz3cJ

Comment: Really? It has to be under the same email? That sucks!